# Compute $\ P\{X_1 = 3 | X = 10 \} $, $\ X \sim Pois(10) $

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

> Suppose $\ X$ is the number of people entering a store in an hour and $\ X \sim Pois(10) $. Compute the probability that at most 3 men enter the store if it is known that 10 women already entered. What assumptions do you make?

I guess the assumption need to make is that the chance of a female \ male entering the store is the same $\ (0.5) $ and therefore the number of men entering the store is also poisson distribution with $\ \lambda = 5 $ ?

Not sure how to proceed from here (if it is true)? Lets say  $\ X_1 $ is number of men entering the store (with the values $\ 0,1,2,3 $ ) and $\ X_2 $ number of women.

$\ P\{X_1 = 3 | X_2 = 10 \} = \frac{P\{X_1 = 3, X_2 = 10 \}}{P\{X_2 = 10 \}} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since further info lacks you are entitled to go for the following:

$X=X_1+X_2$ where $X_1,X_2$ are *iid* and have Poisson distribution with rate $\lambda=5$.

The independence tells us that: $$P(X_1\leq3\mid X_2=10)=P(X_1\leq3)$$

Comment: You mean $\ X_1 , X_2 $ are the number of the men and women entering the store with $\ \lambda = 5 $ each??

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. Then $X=X_1+X_2$ has Poisson distribution with rate $10$. The number of men entering the shop will not depend on the number of women (unless they come by e.g. pairs, but no info is given about that).